# Difficulty displaying price on price scale for line in indicator [Pinescript/TradingView]

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I'm trying to get the ath and atl prices to display on the price line. I would like to have price appear like it does for other lines by default in TradingView - [chart displaying what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvggL.png)

I thought this would be possible to do with line.new but this is not the case. Not sure what to do instead or how to proceed.

```
//@version=5
indicator('All-Time High/Low', shorttitle='ATH/ATL', overlay=true)

////////////
// INPUTS //

show_ath   = input(true,  "Show All Time High?")
show_atl   = input(true, "Show All Time Low?")
show_table = input(false,  "Show table with stats?")

///////////////
// FUNCTIONS //

// all-time high function
get_all_time_high() =>
    h  = 0.0
    t  = 0
    h := bar_index == 0 ? high : high > h[1] ? high : h[1]
    t := bar_index == 0 ? time : high > h[1] ? time : t[1]
    [h, t]

// all-time low function   
get_all_time_low() =>
    l = 0.0
    t = 0
    l := bar_index == 0 ? low  : low < l[1] ? low  : l[1]
    t := bar_index == 0 ? time : low < l[1] ? time : t[1]
    [l, t]

// getting all-time high/low    
[ath, ath_dt] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', get_all_time_high())
[atl, atl_dt] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', get_all_time_low())

ath_days = math.round((timenow - ath_dt) / 86400000)
atl_days = math.round((timenow - atl_dt) / 86400000)

// plotting
if show_ath
    lATH=line.new(bar_index - 1, ath, bar_index, ath, extend = extend.both, color = color.orange, style = line.style_dashed)
    line.delete(lATH[1])
    
if show_atl
    lATL=line.new(bar_index - 1, atl, bar_index, atl, extend = extend.both, color = color.orange, style = line.style_dashed)
    line.delete(lATL[1])

if show_table
    var table ATHtable = table.new(position.bottom_right, 6, 3, frame_color = color.gray, bgcolor = color.gray, border_width = 1, frame_width = 1, border_color = color.white)

    ath_time = str.tostring(year(ath_dt)) + "-" + str.tostring(month(ath_dt)) + "-" + str.tostring(dayofmonth(ath_dt))
    atl_time = str.tostring(year(atl_dt)) + "-" + str.tostring(month(atl_dt)) + "-" + str.tostring(dayofmonth(atl_dt))

    // Header
    table.cell(ATHtable, 0, 0, "",         bgcolor = #cccccc)
    table.cell(ATHtable, 1, 0, "When?",    bgcolor = #cccccc)
    table.cell(ATHtable, 2, 0, "Days ago", bgcolor = #cccccc)
    table.cell(ATHtable, 3, 0, "Price",    bgcolor = #cccccc)
    table.cell(ATHtable, 4, 0, "% away",   bgcolor = #cccccc)
    table.cell(ATHtable, 5, 0, "$ away",   bgcolor = #cccccc)
    
    if (show_ath)
        // ATH
        table.cell(ATHtable, 0, 1, "ATH",                                                  bgcolor = #cccccc)
        table.cell(ATHtable, 1, 1, ath_time,                                               bgcolor = color.new(color.green, transp = 50))
        table.cell(ATHtable, 2, 1, str.tostring(ath_days),                                 bgcolor = color.new(color.green, transp = 50))
        table.cell(ATHtable, 3, 1, str.tostring(ath, format.mintick),                      bgcolor = color.new(color.green, transp = 50))
        table.cell(ATHtable, 4, 1, str.tostring(((ath / close) - 1) * 100 , "#.##") + "%", bgcolor = color.new(color.green, transp = 50))
        table.cell(ATHtable, 5, 1, str.tostring(ath - close , format.mintick),             bgcolor = color.new(color.green, transp = 50))
    
    if (show_atl)
        // ATL
        table.cell(ATHtable, 0, 2, "ATL",                                                  bgcolor = #cccccc)
        table.cell(ATHtable, 1, 2, atl_time,                                               bgcolor = color.new(color.red, transp = 50))
        table.cell(ATHtable, 2, 2, str.tostring(atl_days),                                 bgcolor = color.new(color.red, transp = 50))
        table.cell(ATHtable, 3, 2, str.tostring(atl, format.mintick),                      bgcolor = color.new(color.red, transp = 50))
        table.cell(ATHtable, 4, 2, str.tostring(((atl / close) - 1) * 100 , "#.##") + "%", bgcolor = color.new(color.red, transp = 50))
        table.cell(ATHtable, 5, 2, str.tostring(atl - close, format.mintick),              bgcolor = color.new(color.red, transp = 50))

// alerts
alertcondition(ta.crossover(high, ath), 'All-time High!', 'All-time High!')
alertcondition(ta.crossunder(low, atl), 'All-time Low!',  'All-time Low!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `label` to do so:

```
label.new(chart.right_visible_bar_time, ath, str.tostring(ath), xloc=xloc.bar_time)
label.new(chart.right_visible_bar_time, atl, str.tostring(atl), xloc=xloc.bar_time)
```

You can tweak the style the way you want it of course.